# Design a layout with one div on 2 columns and 2 rows at the left, and 4 divs on 2 columns and 2 rows at the right, similar to BBC website

Tags: html, css

I want to design a hero section similar to BBC website. I started working on this using `CSS Grid` which I thought could get the same design with minimal code.

[image]

I have managed to base design but I want item1 to take 50% of the container's width and rest of the items to take 25% of space each so that it looks like the image above. I can span rows but I am not sure how I can span columns correctly, I tried this :

```
.item1 {
   grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

But it broke the design and same did happen with:

```
.item1 {
   grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

My code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 0px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
.grid-container div img {width:100%; max-width:600px;}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f09c00/fafafa&text=1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010f0/fafafa&text=2"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/5310f0/fafafa&text=3"/>
  </div>  
  <div class="item4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010f0/fafafa&text=4"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item5">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010f0/fafafa&text=5"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as below. I simplified the code by removing irrelevant code for the desired layout and added comments.

```css
.grid-container {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  /* with these 3 lines below, I'm creating a grid of 4 columns and 2 rows*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-of-type(1){ /* I grab the first div */
  grid-column: 1 / 3; /* I tell him to take 2 columns, 1 -> 3 with 3 excluded */
  grid-row: 1 / 3;    /* I tell him to take 2 rows, 1 -> 3 with 3 excluded */
}

.grid-container div img {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;

}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f09c00/fafafa&text=1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010f0/fafafa&text=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/5310f0/fafafa&text=3" />
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010f0/fafafa&text=4" />
  </div>
  <div class="item5">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0010f0/fafafa&text=5" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, could you please share details about the changes as it seems to work as desired.. even with different image size as in actual requirement i will be pulling data from blogs and each blog has 2-3 different dimension of image such as 600x400, 600x350 etc and it works correctly.. i will make other changes so that it works fine for mobile version also

Comment: Glad I could help. I added comments in the code, take a look please.

Comment: Appreciate solution you recommend, i am so happy that it could be achieved with minimal code, i had done same using list li and lot of css. and this just in less than 15 lines of code. I will mark you answer correct as i am not sure if we can improve it further..